# Keyboard friendly light weight UML modeling tool?

Tags: uml, modeling

I'm looking for a free UML tool that runs on Windows and lets me create simple diagrams very fast, with as little mouse fiddling as possible.

I have no need for code generation or fancy stuff, just UML style boxes with arrows.

What I would like is something that for example lets me add a new class with a keyboard shortcut and lets me enter the name without having to double click the added class or something like that. Just a simple app that let you model efficiently without getting the urge to eat your desk...

What I don't want is to have to drag an item from a toolbox to the surface, double click the item, enter the name, grab the mouse again, click the ok button, rince and repeat.

For Eclipse there is [TextUML](http://abstratt.com/) that lets you create diagrams using a textual notation, but I want it for .Net development and I don't want to run Eclipse just for a tiny diagramming plugin.

I have tried quite a few of the open source tools out there, but most of them have quite an awful user experience.

So, is there a tool that fits the above description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really just want boxes with arrows, use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/). It allows you to enter textual descriptions and the current Windows version is now able to provide a graphical preview of the text file. You can choose different shape types and it will allow you produce diagrams even as fancy as the following one.

I have a full-blown UML tool (the superb [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/)) but I still use GraphViz daily for simple sketch diagrams.

For more traditional UML examples with GraphViz see [this blog](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php) and the [UMLGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) site.

```
digraph {

/* notes */
    subgraph cluster_legend {
    graph [color=lightyellow style=filled]
    node[shape=plaintext]
    edge[style=invisible arrowhead=none]
    Mac[label="On Macintosh\nonly" color=blue fontcolor=blue]
    Next[label="Next Version" color=grey fontcolor=grey]
    Mac->Next
}

edge [color=black fontcolor=black]
node [weight=bold fontsize=14 color=black fontcolor=black]


/* docs */
node[ shape=box3d]
AppMakerv2[label="AppMaker V2\nDocument" color=blue fontcolor=blue]
AppMakerX[label="AppMakerX\nDocument"]

/* Code */
node [shape=folder]
PP[label="PowerPlant\nPPob Resources" color=blue fontcolor=blue]
Classic[label="Classic Mac\nResource fork:\nMENU, DLOG, DITL" color=blue fontcolor=blue]
XAML
WPFApp[label="WPF Application\nXAML resources\nC# Code and properties"]
REALBasic[label="REALbasic Application\nXML format\nwindows and code" color=grey fontcolor=grey]
Cocoa[label="Cocoa Application\nxib resources\nObjective-C Code" color=grey fontcolor=grey]
hand[label="Hand Editing in\nAppMaker v2 GUI" shape=plaintext fontcolor=blue]

/* processes */
node[shape=ellipse]
Importer[color=blue fontcolor=blue]
Exporter[color=blue fontcolor=blue]
Converter
WPFGen[label="WPF\nGenerator"]
CocoaGen[label="Cocoa\nGenerator" color=grey fontcolor=grey]
RBGen[label="REALbasic\nGenerator" color=grey fontcolor=grey]


/* Mac workflow */
edge[color=blue]
PP->Importer
Classic->Importer
hand->AppMakerv2
Importer->AppMakerv2
AppMakerv2->Exporter->AppMakerX

/* cross-platform workflow */
edge[color=black]
XAML->Converter->AppMakerX
AppMakerX->WPFGen->WPFApp

/* future workflow */
edge [color=grey fontcolor=grey]
AppMakerX->CocoaGen->Cocoa
AppMakerX->RBGen->REALBasic

}
```

[alt text http://www.aussiedesignedsoftware.com/AppMakerX/files/amxworkflow.png](http://www.aussiedesignedsoftware.com/AppMakerX/files/amxworkflow.png)

Answer (score 2):

try trace2uml
http://trace2uml.tigris.org/

it is free, easy to use and light

Comment: That looks like a really nice syntax. I'll definitely check that one out.

Comment: Looks like you can only create sequence diagrams with it but nut structural diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I find JUDE very good, lightweight software for modeling in UML. It's cross-platform, has community edition, it's easy to use, supports standard UML and diagrams look very nice.

http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/index.html