# Library to Generate UML Diagrams

Tags: c#, uml

My project actually use XML files to define flow of the application.

I like to convert this XML a image that represent the flow, to use it in the documentation.

There is any c# library that help with the graphical part of a UML generation?
There is any XML standard format to generate UML flows that can be converted to IMG?

I need something like this
[image: LampFlowChart]

Comment: It sounds like you want to try and write code in c# to call a library to convert some xml to uml.  Check out my answer, I haven't used it, but it looks like an app that will do this for you.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. Maybe it should be "C# Library to Generate UML Diagrams"

Comment: Also, do you want to create a data flow diagram or something?

Comment: You could write an xslt that turns your xml into SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use GraphViz to model things like this. No, there's no particular .Net component to do it but you can fairly trivially generate the simple textual version of Graphviz and then run the command-line to generate the diagram and render it to your choice of png, svg etc.

You can see an example in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590821/keyboard-friendly-light-weight-uml-modeling-tool/590877#590877) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590821/keyboard-friendly-light-weight-uml-modeling-tool).

**Update 2018-06-07**

Recently I've been using another tool which puts easier syntax on top of GraphViz - [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/). There's a great online version [PlantText](https://www.planttext.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://www.xmlmodeling.com/

Comment: Cool tool, but I think the OP is talking about creating data flow diagrams.

Comment: Ya, It sounded like they either wanted to generate UML from existing XML based representations of their system, or generate DFDs.  I went with the first. :)

Comment: I'm trying to generate something like this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LampFlowchart.svg